# Is any representation equivalent to a unitary one?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I work in a compact or finite group.

First question (just to check) :
**Can I say that any representation is equivalent to a unitary one ?**

And as the unitary representations are always completly reducible, thus any representation of a finite or compact group is completely reducible.

I have seen the equivalence property somewhere but I don't find a proof for it (and I would check with you if it is true indeed).

Second question : (if the first is true) :
Is there an **easy** proof for "a representation is equivalent to a unitary one" for compact groups ? I know some linear algebra (but I am not very very familiar with Hilbert space from a rigorous math point of view).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are not totally clear about the two representations being equivalent and the meaning of a unitary representation.

**Equivalent representations**

> Let $V$ and $W$ be representations of a group $G$. A *morphism* $f:V\to W$ is a linear and equivariant map, i.e., for all $g \in G$ and $v
> \in V$ $f(gv)=gf(v)$ (basically morphisms of vectorspaces or in
>   general of $G-$modules). If such a morphism has an inverse we call it
>   an *isomorphism* and the representations $V$ and $W$ *equivalent*.

**Unitary representation**

> Let $G$ be a compact group and $V$ a representation of $G$. An inner
>   product $V \times V \to \mathbb C$ is called $G-$invariant if $\langle
> gu,gv \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle$ holds for all $g \in G$ and for
>   all $v,u \in V$. A representation together with a $G-$invariant inner
>   product is called a *unitary representation*.

The following fact is not hard to prove: Every representation $V$ of a compact group possesses a $G-$invariant inner product.

Let $b:V\times V \to \mathbb C$ be any inner product and define $$c(u,v) = \int_G~b(gu,gv) \operatorname{d}g$$ where the integral is normalized and left-invariant (this is a so called *Haar-integral* which exists on every compact group and which is unique). Let's check if $c$ defines a $G-$invariant inner product: $c$ is linear in $u$ and conjugate linear in $v$ (since $b$ is a (hermitian) inner product). $c$ is $G-$invariant since the integral is left-invariant and $c$ is positive definite since the integral of a positive continuous function is positive.

Therefore $c$ is a $G-$invariant inner product and $V$ together with $c$ a unitary representation.

In the case of finite groups you can use sums instead of the integral and everything should work in a very similar matter.

Comment: The sum *is* an integral (with respect to the counting measure).

Comment: Thanks a lot, very nice answer ! So to summarize because of the existence of the Haar integral, we can define a "new" scalar product on vectors. And for this new scalar product, we have unitary representations (indeed it is a scalar product G invariant because the Haar integral is left invariant).

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, assuming the characteristic is zero. Indeed you can deform a scalar product $(-,-)$ into a $G$-invariant scalar product $\langle -,- \rangle$ if $G$ is compact or finite, defining $\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{g \in G} (gx,gy)$. Your new scalar product is preserved by $G$, thus chaning of basis you get an unitary representation.

If $G$ is compact you should integrate instead of summing, but really it is completely elementary and exactly the same idea. As you said this is indeed the key step for proving Maschke's theorem (again, assuming the characteristic is zero), because if $U$ is $G$-invariant, then $U^{\perp}$ is a $G$-invariant complementary subspace.

Comment: A little remark : I said it's elementary to remplace $G$ finite by compact but in fact you need to know how to integrate functions over a compact group : you need a measure, called the Haar measure, with property that $\nu(G) = 1$ and $\nu$ is $G$-invariant. The existence and the invariance property of $\nu$ are enough for show that one can apply the same argument to a compact group.